# How can I write/replace a value pointed by JSONATA expression?

Tags: java, jsonata

I am using Jsonata4Java from IBM. I have to write a value to the path defined by the jsonata expression.
How can I do this?

I have a JSON like:

```
{
  "Account": {
    "Account Name": "Firefly",
    "OrderID": "order104",
    "Product": [
      {
        "Product Name": "Bowler Hat",
        "ProductID": 858383,
        "SKU": "040657863",
        "Description": {
          "Colour": "Purple",
          "Width": 300,
          "Height": 200,
          "Depth": 210,
          "Weight": 0.75
        },
        "Price": 34.45,
        "Quantity": 4
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to replace the value at expression **Account.OrderID** with 1234.

I am using Jsonata4Java from IBM, could someone please explain how can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how feature-complete `Jsonata4Java` is, but using vanilla JSONata you can apply the [transform operator](https://docs.jsonata.org/other-operators#-------transform):

```
$$ ~> |Account|{ "OrderID": "1234" }|
```

Playground link: https://stedi.link/FtvEc96

Answer (score 0):

You can use this JSONata Java lib: https://github.com/dashjoin/jsonata-java

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.dashjoin</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsonata</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.1</version>
</dependency>
```

```
import java.util.Map;
import com.dashjoin.jsonata.Jsonata;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Map data = Map.of("Account", Map.of("OrderID", "order104"));
    Jsonata ex = Jsonata.jsonata("$ ~> | Account | {\"OrderID\":1234} | ");
    System.out.println(ex.evaluate(data));
  }
}
```